# How to search again in data state after set state function

Tags: reactjs

Hello everyone I am beginner at react. I want to search i my state which array of object I write the following function for the search. It works perfectly fine to search for the first time.

But when I try to search for the second time it does't work because "tempdata" is now in state. Can anyone please help me to sort?

Here are my code please have a look thanks in Advance.

```
categorySearch(event){

    let tempdata=[];
    this.state.data.map((categoryObject,index) => {
        if(categoryObject.name.includes(event.target.value)){
            tempdata.push(categoryObject);
        }       
        this.setState({data:tempdata});  
    }); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `filter` is a better option here instead of `map`?

Filter returns a new array with all the items that passed the internal conditional - in your case the String `includes` method.

```
categorySearch(event){
    const filteredElements = 
       this.state.data.filter(categoryObject => categoryObject.name.includes(event.target.value));
    this.setState({filteredElements: filteredElements});  
}
```

Additionally, I suggest keeping your original data unmodified and use a new key in your state `filteredElements` to store all the search results that match the search query. That way if you want to do a second search, all the original data is still available.

Comment: Thanks sir it works in console but not working in DOM

Comment: because i display data through  this.state.data.map((item,index) 
now can you please guide me what i can do to display it in DOM

Comment: @ItizazAdil why it doesn't work in DOM? You need to provide an example demonstrating the problem. Probably in a separate question.

Comment: Sir
here is the code for list
{
          this.state.data.map((item,index) => {
           
            return (
              <div key={index} id="area">
                <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                <div id="overflowTest"><List lists={item.lists} handle={this.handleItemClicked} /> </div>
              </div>
            )
          }
        }

Comment: @ItizazAdil if you copied the example from my answer then you should use property different property `this.state.filteredElements.map(...`

Comment: Thanks Sir for your time but if use this.state.filteredElements.map() then no list create cusz i push list to data and if i replace data by filteredElements in all my code then it is same condition as it was frist

Comment: @ItizazAdil create a separate question with a full example and I'm pretty sure someone will help you :)

Comment: Okay Thanks for your time.